# How to vary result of LISTAGG() depending on number of aggregated elements in Oracle 11g+?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregation, listagg

How to print different output within LISTAGG() depending on number of aggregated elements?

Is it possible to get number of aggreated elements without additional COUNT(*) query?

There is an example DDL:

```sql
create table shepherds (
  SHEPHERD_ID NUMBER(19),
  SHEPHERD_NAME VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
);

create table sheeps (
  SHEEP_ID VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
  SHEEP_NAME VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  SHEEP_SHEPHERD_ID NUMBER(19)
);

-- insert shepherds
insert into shepherds VALUES (111, 'Asher');
insert into shepherds VALUES (222, 'Joseph');
insert into shepherds VALUES (333, 'Nicodemus');

-- first shepherd (one sheep)
insert into sheeps VALUES ('A', 'Mark', 111); 

-- second shepherd (two sheeps)
insert into sheeps VALUES ('A', 'Andres', 222);
insert into sheeps VALUES ('B', 'Jeffrey', 222);

-- third shepherd (three sheeps)
insert into sheeps VALUES ('B', 'Jeffrey', 333);
insert into sheeps VALUES ('A', 'Andres', 333);
insert into sheeps VALUES ('D', 'Andres', 333);
```

Now I want to display all shepherds with new-line separated sheep names in the following way:

```sql
SELECT
  SHEPHERD_NAME,
  (SELECT
     listagg(SHEEP_ID || ': ' || SHEEP_NAME, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SHEEP_ID)
   FROM SHEEPS
   WHERE SHEEP_SHEPHERD_ID = SHEPHERD_ID)
FROM SHEPHERDS;
```

The result is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/881a7/3

However, I want to hide sheep's ID letter for those shepherds who have only one sheep.

I tried the following:

```sql
SELECT
  SHEPHERD_NAME,
  (SELECT
     listagg(
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN SHEEP_ID || ': ' ELSE '' END
       || SHEEP_NAME, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SHEEP_ID)
   FROM SHEEPS
   WHERE SHEEP_SHEPHERD_ID = SHEPHERD_ID)
FROM SHEPHERDS;
```

However, I get error:

> ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/881a7/7

Is it possible to return different string from LISTAGG() if there is only one element to aggregate?

How to detect number of aggregated elements without slowing down query performance in Oracle 11g or higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conditional expression in the subquery should do what you want:

```
SELECT sh.SHEPHERD_NAME, 
        (SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MAX(s.SHEEP_NAME)
                      ELSE LISTAGG(s.SHEEP_ID || ': ' || s.SHEEP_NAME, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.SHEEP_ID)
                 END) as SHEEPS
         FROM SHEEPS s
         WHERE s.SHEEP_SHEPHERD_ID = sh.SHEPHERD_ID
       ) as SHEEPS
FROM SHEPHERDS sh;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19612c74391e4240581aa43e19190a34) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The solution *without a subquery* use a simple `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(*) = 1` to distinct the sheep count and two different `LISTAGG` statements

```
SELECT
  s.SHEPHERD_NAME,
  case when count(*) = 1 then 
   listagg(SHEEP_NAME, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SHEEP_ID)  
  else 
   listagg(SHEEP_ID || ': ' || SHEEP_NAME, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SHEEP_ID) end as SHEEPS
FROM SHEPHERDS s
JOIN SHEEPS sh on s.SHEPHERD_ID = sh.SHEEP_SHEPHERD_ID
GROUP BY s.SHEPHERD_NAME /* add SHEPHERD_ID in GROUP BY if the name is not unique */
```

returns

```
SHEPHERD_NAME, SHEEPS
Asher          Mark
Joseph         A: Andres
               B: Jeffrey
Nicodemus      A: Andres
               B: Jeffrey
               D: Andres
```